# 「Implementing a JIT Compiled Language with Haskell and LLVM」 の4章におけるsoファイルのリンク方法について

Tags: haskell

Implementing a JIT Compiled Language with Haskell and LLVM (http://www.stephendiehl.com/llvm/) を読み進めていたのですが,
4章のExternal Functions節での, soファイルのリンクがうまくいきません.

> % gcc -fPIC -shared cbits.c -o cbits.so
> % ghc cbits.so --make Main.hs -o Main

とするとコンパイルは成功するのですが, 実行すると

> ./Main: error while loading shared libraries: cbits.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

というようなエラーを吐きます.

これが自分で書いたものだけでなく,
git clone した https://github.com/sdiehl/kaleidoscope/tree/master/src/chapter4
のソースコードでも同様のことが起こります.

一応下記のリンクに書いてある解決策に従ってMain.hsにコードを加えたのですが, 同様のエラーを吐きました.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462859/haskell-llvm-general-jit-calling-a-c-function-on-the-fly-stephen-diehls-tutor

どのようにすれば, soファイルを正しくリンクできますか?
また, この場合何が起こっていると考えられますか?

**環境**

> Ubuntu-14.04.2 LTS 64bit
>
> % ldd ./Main
> cbits.so => not found
>
> % ghc --version
> The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.1
>
> % cabal --version
> cabal-install version 1.22.2.0
> using version 1.22.2.0 of the Cabal library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ./Main: error while loading shared libraries: cbits.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

カレントディレクトリに配置されたcbits.soを、Mainの実行時に正しくロードできていません。

とりあえず動かすだけなら、環境変数`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`にカレントディレクトリを追加すれば読み込めると思います。

```
% export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
```

GHCユーザガイド [4.13. Using shared libraries](https://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2014.2.0.0/ghc/users_guide/using-shared-libs.html) に、rpathオプションを指定する例が載っていました。例示の通り、カレントディレクトリからロードさせる場合は `-optl-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` 指定でしょうか。

<del>もしくは、リンク時のコマンドを少しだけ変更すると、期待通りの動作になるかもしれません。</del>

```
% ghc ./cbits.so --make Main.hs -o Main
```

Comment: 教えていただいたexportコマンド使ってsoファイルをHaskell側から使うことができましたが, リンク時のコマンドは教えていただいた様に変更しても同様のエラーになってしまいました.

Comment: `ghc ./cbits.so --make Main.hs -o Main -optl-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN' ` 
とすることで, soファイルを正しくリンクすることができました. 
丁寧な回答ありがとうございました.